# how to list authors in a bibliographic entry?

Tags: bibliographies

How should authors name be separated in a bibliographic entry?

Suppose for example :

```
@article{edgar2000automatic,
  title={Automatic control in microelectronics manufacturing: Practices, challenges, and possibilities},
  author={Edgar, Thomas F and Butler, Stephanie W and Campbell, W Jarrett and Pfeiffer, Carlos and Bode, Christopher and Hwang, Sung Bo and Balakrishnan, KS and Hahn, Juergen},
  journal={Automatica},
  volume={36},
  number={11},
  pages={1567--1603},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

how is the author field supposed to be?

Is it correct to write:

```
name1, surname1, and name2, surname2, and name3, surname3
```

?

EDIT:
Additional problem:
The author list of the following reference

```
@incollection{aryal2014improving,
  title={Improving iForest with Relative Mass},
  author={Aryal, Sunil and Ting, Kai Ming and Wells, Jonathan R. and Washio, Takashi},
  booktitle={Advances in Knowledge Discovery and Data Mining},
  pages={510--521},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

ends with `...,Jonathan R Well, and Takashi Washio`.
It ends with `,` and `and`. Where is the error? It seems to follow the proposed rule.

Comment: What's the issue? Is it the comma between the next-to-last and last authors? Is it the "and" conjunction immediately before the final author? Please clarify. Separately, are you sure that there's no "." (period) after "R" in "Jonathan R Well"? Also, is there no space immediately before "Jonathan"?

Comment: Yes the problem is the coma before the and`, and Takashi Washio`.  I tried to use both `R` and `R.` but the result is the same

Comment: Well, the comma -- the so-called "Oxford comma" -- is put there by the bib style you use (`plain`, right?). It's a specific design choice. You're not making a mistake.

Comment: If I compile your sample bib entry with the `plain` bibliography style, I definitely get a `.` after "R" -- the author being entered as `Wells, Jonathan R` -- and I also get a space before "Jonathan".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the `author` field either as

```
author = {Edgar, Thomas F. and Butler, Stephanie W. and Campbell, W. Jarrett 
    and Pfeiffer, Carlos and Bode, Christopher and Hwang, Sung Bo 
    and Balakrishnan, K. S. and Hahn, J{\"u}rgen},
```

or as

```
author = {Thomas F. Edgar and Stephanie W. Butler and W. Jarrett Campbell 
    and Carlos Pfeiffer and Christopher Bode and Sung Bo Hwang 
    and K.S. Balakrishnan and J{\"u}rgen Hahn},
```

In short:

- Use the keyword `and` between authors
- Use commas if (and only if) you wish to place surnames *before* given names
- Do place `.` (periods, "full stops") after abbreviated first and middle names.

For sure,

```
name1, surname1, and name2, surname2, and name3, surname3
```

is wrong *for two reasons*: (i) there should be be no commas between the (given) names and the associated surnames and (ii) there should be no commas after the surnames either.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: @Donbeo - which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: `\bibliographystyle{plain}`